# compile a fortran code in an other server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, fortran

I am a beginner in Linux. I have a Fortran code that I can run it in my own server,but when the same package is copied to an other server,it is not work.

in my server i type this in terminal program:

```
sami@sami-VGN-CS118E:~/Downloads/softwares/eerad3$ ./eerad3 -i eerad3.input
```

in my server i have installed Fortran compiler,so the program is worked.

the other server i write:

```
root@debian7-virtual:/home/softwares/eerad3# ./eerad3 -i eerad3.input
```

and i got:

```
-bash: ./eerad3: No such file or directory
```

at first i thought maybe its due of Fortran compiler,so i type:

```
root@debian7-virtual:/home/softwares/eerad3# sudo apt-get install g77
```

but again i got:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

the problem isn't due to `$` and `#`?

Comment: With `./eerad3` you go to execute the command `eerad3` in the present directory. Are you sure that you are in the correct directory?

Comment: Close voters: This is not off-topic! The question is about running software on Ubuntu, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

When your shell shows `#` that means you are already privileged and do not need to `sudo`. If you are non-privileged yet, you can use `sudo` but you have to install `sudo` first using `apt-get install sudo` (as privileged).

Comment: The use of "#" in the root prompt is the default, but you cannot be sure only from that... you can use `whoami` (all in one word), `id -u`  or `echo $EUID` (the last two answer 0 if you are  root).

Comment: seems it is due of use of root (instead of sudo apt get install, i should use apt get install)and also,i had to install make command,and then use it.i found out in server B,no command installed.